# Creating custom statistic type for use in focal statistics in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, focal-statistics

I am trying to analyze raster data using a moving window. I am doing this in ArcGIS Pro, but at this point I'm getting stuck on how to use the formula I need as the statistic type of the moving window.

The focal statistics tool in ArcGIS Pro does exactly what I need from a "moving window", but none of the preset "Statistic Types" will work for the analysis I need to do. The actual formula I need applied to each cell is `X = (A1/A2) ^ (1/T) -1`. In this scenario A1 is the area of all cells classified as 2, A2 is the area of all cells classified as 1 or 2, and T will be a constant integer based on the timeframe my data is originating from.

I am wondering if there is a way for me to define a new statistics type, then call that statistic instead of the preset ones while running focal statistics?

So far I have tried creating formulas right in the section of the Python code that the statistic type goes in but that is not working how I was hoping it would. Here is an example of what I tried to do just as a test:

```
import arcpy  
from arcpy import env  
from arcpy.sa import *  
env.workspace = r"C:Imagery\Python_Testing"  
outFocalStat = FocalStatistics("ExistingForest2000.tif", NbrRectangle(5, 5, "CELL"), 'SUM' * 26, "NODATA")  
outFocalStat.save(r"C:Imagery\Python_Testing\Test5X5")
```

When I ran this script the output was just the sum of the value of the cells in the moving 5X5 window, it did not multiply that sum by 26.

Comment: If you also want to ask about how to do this using Python without ArcPy then please do that in a separate question so that this one can remain focused on using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro and Spatial Analyst.

Comment: Create binary files first, one for cells = 2,  2nd for 1 and 2. Compute separately A1 and A2, use your formula.

Comment: How are you going to deal with the situation where both A1 and A2 are zero because you can't divide by zero? Is that a scenario that will not exist in your dataset, suggest you edit your question and explain your inputs, may be with an image?

Comment: The NoData scenario is not a problem, the areas where it occurs will not be a part of my final data set, I'll be clipping those areas out. I've figured out how to do what I needed to in ArcGIS pro. It is not an elegant solution but it gets the job done.